# A questions about the schur's lemma

Tags: representation-theory, harmonic-analysis

Schur's lemma is this:

If (ρ1,V1) and (ρ2,V2) are irreducible representations of a group G, then any nonzero homomorphism ϕ:V1↦V2 is an isomorphism.

or

> Schur's Lemma.
>   a.
>     A unitary representation ρ of G is irreducible if and only if C(ρ)
>   contains only scalar multiples of the identity.
>   b. Suppose ρ1 and ρ2 are irreducible unitary representations of G. If
>   ρ1 and ρ2 are equivalent then C( ρ1, ρ2) is one-dimensional; otherwise,
>   C(ρI,ρ2) = {0}.

Whether these two are equivalent?
If the answer is yes ,how  isomorphism of  ϕ causes that C( ρ1, ρ2) is one-dimensional?

Comment: Are we talking about finite groups and finite-dimensional spaces?

Comment: G is a locally compact group.

Answer (score 4):

The first version of Schur's lemma is more general than the second (indeed it applies e.g. to simple modules over arbitrary rings, not just group algebras). It implies that if $V$ is an irreducible representation then $\text{End}(V)$ is a division ring. Now if $V$ is finite-dimensional over the base field $k$ then so is $\text{End}(V)$, but now it's an exercise to show that if $k$ is algebraically closed then the only finite-dimensional division ring over $k$ is $k$ itself. Hence in particular if $k = \mathbb{C}$ then $\text{End}(V) \cong \mathbb{C}$ consists of only scalar multiples of the identity.

(The more general version of Schur's lemma is important even in representation theory. For example, over $\mathbb{R}$ it implies that $\text{End}(V)$ must be one of $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$, or $\mathbb{H}$, and the distinction is important for understanding how real and complex representations relate to each other. See [Frobenius-Schur indicator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius%E2%80%93Schur_indicator) for more details.)

Comment: @ Qiaochu Yuan : thank you.I want to prove the second.Can I use the isomorphism the first one?